# Finding distance from every point in one layer and every feature in another using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: distance, arcgis-pro, proximity

I have two layers.  One contains points (lat/lng) and the other contains lakes (polygons).  I want to generate a table that shows, for every point, the distance to every lake.

What tool in the toolbox is designed for this task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like the use case for the [Generate Near Table](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/analysis/generate-near-table.htm) tool which:

> Calculates distances and other proximity information between features
>   in one or more feature class or layer. Unlike the Near tool, which
>   modifies the input, Generate Near Table writes results to a new
>   stand-alone table and supports finding more than one near feature.